# Factory reset Sony Xperia J with forgotten pattern code

Tags: lock-screens, factory-reset, locked-out, pattern-lock, sony-xperia-j

My friend asked me if it's still possible to factory reset his Sony Xperia J phone in any way when the pattern code was entered 20 times and it locked itself. The only way to do it right now is to enter the answer to the question, but he doesn't even remember it. The second one's validating through a Google account, but he doesn't remember his credentials.

I tried the volume up/down/both + power button, didn't seem to work, the menu won't show up. I tried flashing it, but it's locked and when I tried to unlock it, writing the code in the emergency dialer didn't do anything too. Additionally, other codes didn't look like working too. No menus showed up.

Is it possible to factory reset this phone? I don't care about data loss, I've already taken both SIM and SD cards out where all the information was.

Comment: need to ask the obvious question... have you tried booting into recovery? Power off your device.
Boot in recovery mode by pressing and holding Volume Up and Power Button at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Download an app called "PC Companion" ([Link](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/))
2. Install and run it.
3. Select the option "Support Zone New!" then click "Start"
4. Wait for the program to install an add-on
5. Select "Phone / Tablet Software Update" and click "Start"
6. Select "Repair my phone / tablet"
7. Follow the Instruction
8. Chose your phone model
9. Connect your phone to your PC and wait.

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the phone without needing your PC or any other software:

1. Turn the phone off
2. Long press **Power up** and **Volume up** keys for a couple of seconds. It should start booting.
3. When booted you should see a menu, use the volume keys to navigate to **Restore factory settings**.
4. Use the **Power** button to select.
5. When it asks you to confirm navigate to yes and press the power button again.
6. The phone should reboot and start formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use **fastboot** to wipe user data.

Here's how :

1. Enter into fastboot mode by:

   1. first power off your phone.
   2. Press volume down key and while pressing it connect your phone to pc. The blue light will turn on.
2. Now try these commands( I assume you have fastboot files ) :

   ```
   fastboot wipe userdata
   fastboot erase userdata  # alternative
   ```

   It should probably work.
3. If it stays on waiting for device, you're probably missing the drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, Sony Xperia J doesn't have stock recovery. You need to flash a new one. Try TWRP or CWM from the XDA Developers site.

If the phone's rooted, you can try ADB. But for ADB, you should need the ADB debugging option enabled on the phone.
Write those commands in the ADB shell of your PC.

```
adb devices
adb shell
cd data/system
su
rm *.key
```

OR

On TWRP, mount the system, use file manager, navigate to `/data/system`,
remove all files ending with `.key`.

Done. You got your phone unlocked.